# Error using Selenium (Python): Unable to find class in HTML source code

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, classname

I'm learning how to use Selenium. I was doing some testing, but got this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .layout layout-base

My Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://page.onstove.com/epicseven/global/list/e7en003?listType=2&direction=latest&page=1")
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"layout layout-base")
```

[image: Image of:] The source code I'm trying to find using `find_element`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe try using a sleep to give the site time to load all the elements into the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`layout layout-base` are two class name values separated by a space.
To locate this element you can use any of the following ways:

```py
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"layout.layout-base")
```

Or

```py
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.layout.layout-base")
```

Or

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='layout layout-base']")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass multiple classnames as argument through `find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"classname")` and doing so you will face an error as:

```
invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
```

---

### Solution

As an alternative you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CLASS_NAME* *`layout`*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "layout")
  ```
- Using *CLASS_NAME* *`layout`*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "layout-base")
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".layout.layout-base")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='layout layout-base']")
  ```